# How to get the current locale in Vue i18n plugin?

Tags: vue-i18n

I tried with `this.$i18n.locale` but that only gives me the browser's locale, not the current language being used (I have a default local fallback)
Something like `this.$i18n.currentLanguage` doesn't seem to exist

Answer (score 0):

You could check the current lang setting first a item in local storage and get it's item:

[How to save current language (i18n) in localstorage (Vue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935666/how-to-save-current-language-i18n-in-localstorage-vue)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use This trick will help you!

```
this.$root.$i18n.locale
```